# Can't find any tutorials on Body Edgeloops

Tags: modeling, loop

I can find plenty of tutorials on good edge loops while modelling the head, hands, feet but nothing on the main body itself, any help please?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se. I answered your question. Note, that your question appears to be slightly opinion-based, broad and/or a tutorial request, all of which are off topic. Please read [avoid-asking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [on-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic/6#6) and try to phrase your future question in a more stackexchange-y fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I will compile comments to other questions.
<sup>*Click on the images to enlarge them.*</sup>

[Should I restart my character mesh?](http://Should%20I%20restart%20my%20character%20mesh?)

> There is no need to reinvent anything topology-wise, it has been done many times before by experienced artists. A simple search shows many examples. Just research and copy if you are not as experienced.
>
> - lightwave base mesh
>   [image]
> - upper back and shoulders
>     [image]

From [Are self intersecting edge loops legal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/124833/30849)

> **You want to have the edge loops perpendicular or aligned with the direction of movement/the alignment of the muscles**. The ring muscles should be supported with multiple loops. Self intersecting loops probably are not the best solution, spirals most definitely not.

The Blender Foundation's [*Blenderella* Training course](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenderella/), also focuses on the lower body.
[image: blenderella]